# Animating the Loading... textview continually

Tags: android

Im trying to animate the three dots of "Loading..." textview as follows,

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

        for (int i = 100; i <= 3500; i =i+100) {
            final int finalI = i;
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(finalI %300 == 0){
                        loadigText.setText("Loading.");
                    }else if(finalI %200 == 0){
                        loadigText.setText("Loading..");
                    }else if(finalI %100 == 0){
                        loadigText.setText("Loading...");
                    }
                }
            }, i);
```

The problem is that ,
 1. Im unable to animate it infinitely till the dialog is visible.
 2. Im unable to reduce the speed of Three dots animation,

How can I be able to sort this out

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Example:

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

            int count = 0;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                count++;

                if (count == 1)
                {
                    textView.setText("Loading.");
                }
                else if (count == 2)
                {
                    textView.setText("Loading..");
                }
                else if (count == 3)
                {
                    textView.setText("Loading...");
                }

                if (count == 3)
                    count = 0;

                handler.postDelayed(this, 2 * 1000);
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1 * 1000);
```